# Why are these routes missing from rake routes?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, routes

Rails 3.2.13

I am basically trying to follow the deployment using this screencast: http://railscasts.com/episodes/335-deploying-to-a-vps

I have an app that works in development but when pushed to production with Capistrano one of my controllers actions almost all result in 404 pages.

When I run 'rake routes' I notice this controller's actions are missing from the output:

routes.rb

```
Wagmantechnology::Application.routes.draw do

  root :to => 'static_pages#home'

  resources :users
  resources :sessions, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]
  resources :tasks
  resources :assets

  match '/signup',  to: 'users#new'
  match '/signin',  to: 'sessions#new'
  match '/signout', to: 'sessions#destroy', via: :delete

  match 'tasks/mjhartman' => "tasks#mjhartman", :as => "tasks_mjhartman"
  match 'tasks/ejmcfadden' => "tasks#ejmcfadden", :as => "tasks_ejmcfadden"
  match 'tasks/ctkahler' => "tasks#ctkahler", :as => "tasks_ctkahler"
  match 'tasks/gafc' => "tasks#gafc", :as => "tasks_gafc"
  match 'tasks/wci' => "tasks#wci", :as => "tasks_wci"
  match 'tasks/fsc' => "tasks#fsc", :as => "tasks_fsc"
  match 'tasks/wagco' => "tasks#wagco", :as => "tasks_wagco"
  match 'tasks/it' => "tasks#it", :as => "tasks_it"
  match 'tasks/atf' => "tasks#atf", :as => "tasks_atf"
  match 'tasks/hr' => "tasks#hr", :as => "tasks_hr"
  match 'tasks/legal' => "tasks#legal", :as => "tasks_legal"
  match 'tasks/marketing' => "tasks#marketing", :as => "tasks_marketing"
  match 'tasks/user_request' => "tasks#user_request", :as => "tasks_user_request"
  match 'tasks/jde' => "tasks#jde", :as => "tasks_jde"
  match 'tasks/communications' => "tasks#communications", :as => "tasks_communications"
  match 'tasks/hardware' => "tasks#hardware", :as => "tasks_hardware"
  match 'tasks/software' => "tasks#software", :as => "tasks_software"
  match 'tasks/documentation' => "tasks#documentation", :as => "tasks_documentation"
  match 'tasks/security' => "tasks#security", :as => "tasks_security"
  match 'tasks/billing' => "tasks#billing", :as => "tasks_billing"
  match 'tasks/training' => "tasks#training", :as => "tasks_training"
  match 'tasks/york_gafc' => "tasks#york_gafc", :as => "tasks_york_gafc"
  match 'tasks/york_wci' => "tasks#york_wci", :as => "tasks_york_wci"
  match 'tasks/berryville' => "tasks#berryville", :as => "tasks_berryville"
  match 'tasks/route52' => "tasks#route52", :as => "tasks_route52"
  match 'tasks/gafc_field' => "tasks#gafc_field", :as => "tasks_gafc_field"
  match 'tasks/wci_field' => "tasks#wci_field", :as => "tasks_wci_field"

  match 'assets/laptop' => "assets#laptop", :as => "assets_laptop"
  match 'assets/desktop' => "assets#desktop", :as => "assets_desktop"
  match 'assets/server' => "assets#server", :as => "assets_server"
  match 'assets/network' => "assets#network", :as => "assets_network"
  match 'assets/tablet' => "assets#tablet", :as => "assets_tablet"
  match 'assets/cell' => "assets#cell", :as => "assets_cell"
  match 'assets/data' => "assets#data", :as => "assets_data"
  match 'assets/office' => "assets#office", :as => "assets_office"
  match 'assets/printer' => "assets#printer", :as => "assets_printer"
  match 'assets/gafc' => "assets#gafc", :as => "assets_gafc"
  match 'assets/wci' => "assets#wci", :as => "assets_wci"
  match 'assets/fsc' => "assets#fsc", :as => "assets_fsc"
  match 'assets/wagco' => "assets#wagco", :as => "assets_wagco"
  match 'assets/it' => "assets#it", :as => "assets_it"
  match 'assets/atf' => "assets#atf", :as => "assets_atf"
  match 'assets/hr' => "assets#hr", :as => "assets_hr"
  match 'assets/legal' => "assets#legal", :as => "assets_legal"
  match 'assets/marketing' => "assets#marketing", :as => "assets_marketing"
  match 'assets/user_request' => "assets#user_request", :as => "assets_user_request"
  match 'assets/jde' => "assets#jde", :as => "assets_jde"
  match 'assets/communications' => "assets#communications", :as => "assets_communications"
  match 'assets/hardware' => "assets#hardware", :as => "assets_hardware"
  match 'assets/software' => "assets#software", :as => "assets_software"
  match 'assets/documentation' => "assets#documentation", :as => "assets_documentation"
  match 'assets/security' => "assets#security", :as => "assets_security"
  match 'assets/billing' => "assets#billing", :as => "assets_billing"
  match 'assets/training' => "assets#training", :as => "assets_training"
  match 'assets/york_gafc' => "assets#york_gafc", :as => "assets_york_gafc"
  match 'assets/york_wci' => "assets#york_wci", :as => "assets_york_wci"
  match 'assets/berryville' => "assets#berryville", :as => "assets_berryville"
  match 'assets/route52' => "assets#route52", :as => "assets_route52"
  match 'assets/gafc_field' => "assets#gafc_field", :as => "assets_gafc_field"
  match 'assets/wci_field' => "assets#wci_field", :as => "assets_wci_field"
  match 'assets/inventory' => "assets#inventory", :as => "assets_inventory"

end
```

The output from 'rake routes':

```
                root        /                               static_pages#home
               users GET    /users(.:format)                users#index
                     POST   /users(.:format)                users#create
            new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)            users#new
           edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)       users#edit
                user GET    /users/:id(.:format)            users#show
                     PUT    /users/:id(.:format)            users#update
                     DELETE /users/:id(.:format)            users#destroy
            sessions POST   /sessions(.:format)             sessions#create
         new_session GET    /sessions/new(.:format)         sessions#new
             session DELETE /sessions/:id(.:format)         sessions#destroy
               tasks GET    /tasks(.:format)                tasks#index
                     POST   /tasks(.:format)                tasks#create
            new_task GET    /tasks/new(.:format)            tasks#new
           edit_task GET    /tasks/:id/edit(.:format)       tasks#edit
                task GET    /tasks/:id(.:format)            tasks#show
                     PUT    /tasks/:id(.:format)            tasks#update
                     DELETE /tasks/:id(.:format)            tasks#destroy
              signup        /signup(.:format)               users#new
              signin        /signin(.:format)               sessions#new
             signout DELETE /signout(.:format)              sessions#destroy
     tasks_mjhartman        /tasks/mjhartman(.:format)      tasks#mjhartman
    tasks_ejmcfadden        /tasks/ejmcfadden(.:format)     tasks#ejmcfadden
      tasks_ctkahler        /tasks/ctkahler(.:format)       tasks#ctkahler
          tasks_gafc        /tasks/gafc(.:format)           tasks#gafc
           tasks_wci        /tasks/wci(.:format)            tasks#wci
           tasks_fsc        /tasks/fsc(.:format)            tasks#fsc
         tasks_wagco        /tasks/wagco(.:format)          tasks#wagco
            tasks_it        /tasks/it(.:format)             tasks#it
           tasks_atf        /tasks/atf(.:format)            tasks#atf
            tasks_hr        /tasks/hr(.:format)             tasks#hr
         tasks_legal        /tasks/legal(.:format)          tasks#legal
     tasks_marketing        /tasks/marketing(.:format)      tasks#marketing
  tasks_user_request        /tasks/user_request(.:format)   tasks#user_request
           tasks_jde        /tasks/jde(.:format)            tasks#jde
tasks_communications        /tasks/communications(.:format) tasks#communications
      tasks_hardware        /tasks/hardware(.:format)       tasks#hardware
      tasks_software        /tasks/software(.:format)       tasks#software
 tasks_documentation        /tasks/documentation(.:format)  tasks#documentation
      tasks_security        /tasks/security(.:format)       tasks#security
       tasks_billing        /tasks/billing(.:format)        tasks#billing
      tasks_training        /tasks/training(.:format)       tasks#training
     tasks_york_gafc        /tasks/york_gafc(.:format)      tasks#york_gafc
      tasks_york_wci        /tasks/york_wci(.:format)       tasks#york_wci
    tasks_berryville        /tasks/berryville(.:format)     tasks#berryville
       tasks_route52        /tasks/route52(.:format)        tasks#route52
    tasks_gafc_field        /tasks/gafc_field(.:format)     tasks#gafc_field
     tasks_wci_field        /tasks/wci_field(.:format)      tasks#wci_field
```

You'll see that none of the asset routes are listed.  Why?  Strangely enough the index action /assets works in production but nothing else.  All links work in development.  What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason should be name conflict with assets pipeline.

The word "assets" in your routing is too sensitive, it's the same as Rails static assets. You can verify that `localhost:3000/assets/rails.png` will work in development env, but not production. All of the "assets" routes have been changed in production mode.

My suggestion is to rename your route namespace from "assets" to something else. But this may involve lots of work. I don't know other simpler way yet.

**Update**
Thanks for @sevenseacat's comment. He pointed out a much simpler way - to change the assets routes

```
config.assets.prefix = "/some_other_path"
```

Ref: assets-path">http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#changing-the-*assets*-path

Comment: Alternatively, you could change the path Rails uses to serve assets - http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#changing-the-\_assets\_-path

Comment: Thank you.  This makes perfect sense but I would not have thought about it.  I ended up changing assets to inventory_items to not conflict with the asset pipeline.  Note:  I first tried changing config.assets.prefix = "/some_other_path" but was unsuccessful.  It seems like that solution may need more than simply that one line.

Comment: @ColinKahler, thank you for the further update. I guess the reason of your failure on one line solution is you forget to rename `/assets` to that in `config.assets.prefix`. If that is true, don't blame me as I thought about it just now :) Anyway I like your renaming the controllers. It's better to keep convention there as much as possible.